# Angular test with Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to use Jasmine framework but karma is sent me an error in the browser. I think the problem is the provider that is use in my component. Bellow the error.

Comment: It appears you don't have DkvHeaderService in providers, it says it there to help you debug it (NullInjectorError: No provider for DkvHeaderService!)

Answer (score 1):

So this fixes your first issue, which you have mentioned:

```
providers: [ AuthService, ReduxStore ]
```

I imagine the second issue, the InjectionToken arises because you have something like this in a component somewhere:

```
export const SINGLE_SPA_STORE_KEY = new InjectionToken<SomeService>('SINGLE_SPA_STORE_KEY');
```

This leads me to think in your app.module you might have something like this:

```
providers: [
  { provide: SINGLE_SPA_STORE_KEY, useExisting: SOME_STORAGE }
]
```

So your test is complaining that it doesn't understand what SINGLE_SPA_STORE_KEY is, so you'll need to tell it explicitly like so:

```
providers: [
  { provide: SINGLE_SPA_STORE_KEY, useValue: SOME_STORAGE }
]
```

This all hinges on possibilities though, without going through all your code this is just a guess. But, it's a guess that I've gone through with my own code so it's very similar.